# How to convert a column of type string to jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry for my English.
I have a table in my database that has a table of type string.
I need to convert the type of that column to jsonb.

I need to convert this:

```
--------------------
table_a
--------------------
id | type (string)
--------------------
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
--------------------
```

for this

```
--------------------
table_a
--------------------
id | type (jsonb)
--------------------
1  | ["aaa"]
2  | ["bbb"]
--------------------
```

I need a sql script to do this.
I've tried to create scripts, but to no avail!

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ALTER the type to be jsonb while converting the values in the same statement

```
alter table the_table
    alter "type" type jsonb
    using  jsonb_build_array ("type");
```